# Unable to run deal.ii on Oracle VM

Tags: oracle, virtual-machine

I can not run my deal.ii on Oracle VM. I don't know what is the problem with my pc configuration. [Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfhMx.png)

Comment: Completely off-topic for this site. [See if this helps](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=62339). If not, search that forum, ask on that forum, search elsewhere, or ask a question on a more suitable site in the Stack Exchange network, like Super User or Server Fault. It's also nothing to do with Oracle RDBMS. And while an image *might* be useful in this case, please describe the error you're getting as part of the question.

Comment: Thanks Alex, actually I am a noob.